# Displaying list of values from a list view into body of an email

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

I am trying to display a list of pickup numbers in a body of an email. I can get the pickup number fine using this code:

```
foreach (LoadRelationship relationship in View.SelectedObjects)
{
///This works fine, I get 3 pickup numbers for my selected records///
    List<string> pickUpNumbers = View.SelectedObjects.Cast<LoadRelationship>()
    .Where(x => x != null && x.PurchaseLoad.PickupNumber != null)
    .Select(x => x.PurchaseLoad.PickupNumber)
    .ToList();
//When assigning the pickUpNumbers.To String to the body of the email it fails here:
e.Report.ExportOptions.Email.Body =  pickUpNumbers.ToString();
}
```

The output in the body of the email is this:

System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]

The out put should be this:

12345
2334556
12334445

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
e.Report.ExportOptions.Email.Body = string.Join(" ", pickUpNumbers);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
foreach (LoadRelationship relationship in View.SelectedObjects)
{
///This works fine, I get 3 pickup numbers for my selected records///
    List<string> pickUpNumbers = View.SelectedObjects.Cast<LoadRelationship>()
    .Where(x => x != null && x.PurchaseLoad.PickupNumber != null)
    .Select(x => x.PurchaseLoad.PickupNumber)
    .ToList();
//When assigning the pickUpNumbers.To String to the body of the email it fails here:

string body = "";
for(int i = 0; i < pickUpNumbers.Count; i++) {
   if (i > 0) {
       body += ", ";
   }
   body += puckUpNumbers[i];
}
e.Report.ExportOptions.Email.Body =  body;


}
```

Answer (score 1):

The output is `System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.String]` because you have a collection of strings and are calling `.ToString()` on the collection directly.

You can get the result you want by iterating over the collection and build the e-mail body up.

For instance:

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 foreach(var pickupNumber in pickUpNumbers) {
     sb.Append(pickupNumber);
 }

 e.Report.ExportOptions.Email.Body = sb.ToString();
```

You can also use [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
 e.Report.ExportOptions.Email.Body = string.Join(" ", pickUpNumbers);
```